# global .gitignore not ignoring files

Tags: git

So I thought I am smart and downloaded the recommended gitignore repo and and wrote a script that makes one big gitignore out off all of them and be set for an easy future with git.

I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3LYBdd3RGKs
[git knows the file exists and has access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhCIk.png)

I looked at a lot of tutorials and they all end up verifying with that line.

I thought maybe gitignores have a size limit but i didn't find anything hinting at that.

Comment: Could you add some punctuation to make your question more readable? And explain what you mean with the "recommended" gitignore?

Comment: my question shows up structured in 4 paragraphs for me, sorry if it doesnt work everwhere im new here. Also i was refering to this repo on github: https://github.com/github/gitignore

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A "global" .gitignore (one which would apply to *all* your local repositories) would be a file reference by `git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore` (as [seen here](http://egorsmirnov.me/2015/05/04/global-gitignore-file.html) or [here](https://sebastiandedeyne.com/setting-up-a-global-gitignore-file/))

But don't forget it won't applied automatically to files already tracked in a repository.
For a file already committed, you would need to rm it first (`git rm --cached -- aFile`)

Then you can check it is indeed ignored with:

```
git check-ignore -v -- aFile
```

Comment: so the global gitignore has to be in the root folder? since i have different path set it doesn't work?                    https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhCIk.png

Comment: It can be anywhere you want, as long as the file exists. And again, how do you test it? Because on existing tracked file, it won't apply. It will only on private files or new files (not yet added/committed)

Comment: I created some demo files now and checked your recommended command `git check-ignore -v -- aFile`, and am thankful to report it works as you described it

Comment: This comment is so useful as other answers on web fail to mention removing file from cache. Thanks